# SpriteKit adding subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I am trying to implement a pause menu to my game using addSubview . But when i touch the pause button the view presents the subview over the previous scene - DTStartMenu scene , and not over the actual game scene.
Here is the code in ViewController.m :

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    skView.showsFPS = YES;
    skView.showsNodeCount = YES;

    // Create and configure the scene.
    SKScene * scene = [DTStartMenu sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

    // Present the scene.
    [skView presentScene:scene];
}
```

code in the StartMenu.m

```
    -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    /* Called when a touch begins */
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    SKScene *gameScene = [DTGame sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
    gameScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

   // [self.view presentScene:gameScene transition:[SKTransition fadeWithDuration:1]];
    [self.view presentScene:gameScene];
}
```

The code in DTGame.m

```
-(void) didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {

    skview = (SKView*)self.view;

}
-(void)pauseGame{
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(90, 40, 300, 200);
    pauseMenu = [[DTPauseMenu alloc] initWithFrame:rect];

    [skview addSubview:pauseMenu];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Common problem. You don't check whether scene is already set in the view. Try this:

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    if (skView.scene == nil)
    {
        // Setup and present the scene here....
        [skView presentScene:scene];
    }
}
```

Note that I changed it from viewDid.. to viewWill.. and also calls the correct super method (your implementation called viewDidLoad).

Comment: Makes sense . Worked . Thank you !